# How to create a plagiarism detector of c++ files

Tags: c++, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, plagiarism-detection

hi a am a student and a have a project "plagiarism detector in c++ and java files" and i am in trouble

i want(i hope to want) to see an example exist , a project in that title or a documentation in this field (in practice part)

Comment: I don't know what plagiarism detection is, because the tag has no wiki summary. What is it?

Comment: @Mr. Lister: It's... the detection of plagiarism...

Comment: So you want to copy the answer of how to create a plagiarism detector from someone else on SO?

Comment: Are you trying to use c++/java to detect plagiarism in text files, or are you trying to detect plagiarism *in the code itself*?

Comment: And that has a tag of its own? Ah... OK.

Comment: The top FAQ in `plagiarism-detection`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294447/how-can-i-find-source-code-copying

Comment: To start, similar file size and line count, then do a checksum of every line and compare to around the same line in the "original" file. Fuzzy text comparison algorithms might be good too.

Comment: This is an open research topic. Google for 'software clones' or 'clone detection'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [a simple lexer.cpp to convert a simle c++ file to a sequence of tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969836/a-simple-lexer-cpp-to-convert-a-simle-c-file-to-a-sequence-of-tokens)

Answer (score 3):

I think firstly you could create `double originality()` measurement function, which will give you float point value between 0 and 1, and then use it for your plagiarism detector via formula `plagiarism = 1. - originality()`. Then you will define threshold level and vous a la.

Comment: And hard problem has been reduced to another hard problem (defining originality() ) plus a bit of work!

Comment: That's who we are, that's how we work :) Looking forward to boost::originality release.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty interesting NLP research topic. Computer, please check all of human knowledge and tell me if my stuff is original

Comment: We shouldn't be limited by borders of human knowledge. Copying bee's cells or dragonfly wings is not original either.