# how to tokenize a c++ source code file (convert to sequence of tokens)?

Tags: c++, c++builder, tokenize, plagiarism-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a plagiarism detector of c++ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687763/how-to-create-a-plagiarism-detector-of-c-files)
>   [a simple lexer.cpp to convert a simle c++ file to a sequence of tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969836/a-simple-lexer-cpp-to-convert-a-simle-c-file-to-a-sequence-of-tokens)

hi i have a project "plagiarism detector for c++ files"

and a need to know how to convert a c++ file to sequence of tokens like that :

```
int factorial(int n) {
if (n == 0) return 1 ;
else return n * factorial(n-1) ;
}
```

into that :

```
Int, factorial, (, int, n, ), {, if, (, n, ==, 0, ), return, 1, ;, else, return, n, *, factorial, (, n, -, 1, ), ;, }
```

Answer (score 2):

One typically writes tokenizers using a lexer generator like [Flex](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/) or using the lexer part of a parser generator like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). A lexer and parser of the C++ grammar, written lex and yacc are [available](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.11).

These lexers boil down (to an extent) to a lot of regular expressions, and some code for switching between modes (e.g. string mode, comment mode, and language mode).